# Python Pandas, get the user rating of all the other movie

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I use python to read a file rating.csv, it has three columns : user_id, tid, and rating. The user rates several teleplays.

[image]

Now I want the row to be all the unique user id and the columns to be all the unique tid. The element (user_id, tid) is the rating. If the user does not rate the teleplay, it places np.nan at it.
Is there any good way to get it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, We want to help you solve your problem. but we would love if you learned to solve it yourself. By showing us what you did we can advise you, push you further, make you a better programmer along the way. So please show us what you have done so far and what problems you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pandas`' pivot method

```
df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='tid', values='rating')
```